# Authentification to kubernetes api via Azure Active Directory (AKS)

Tags: python, kubernetes, azure-aks

I would like to use python [kubernetes-client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) to connect to my AKS cluster api.

To do that I try to use the example give by kubernetes:

```
config.load_kube_config()

v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
print("Listing pods with their IPs:")
ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
for i in ret.items:
    print("%s\t%s\t%s" % (i.status.pod_ip, i.metadata.namespace, i.metadata.name))
```

It is supposed to load my local kubeconfig and get a pods list but I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 4, in
>   
>       config.load_kube_config()   File "/Users//works/test-kube-api-python/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py",
>   line 661, in load_kube_config
>       loader.load_and_set(config)   File "/Users//works/test-kube-api-python/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py",
>   line 469, in load_and_set
>       self._load_authentication()   File "/Users//works/test-kube-api-python/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py",
>   line 203, in _load_authentication
>       if self._load_auth_provider_token():   File "/Users//works/test-kube-api-python/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py",
>   line 221, in _load_auth_provider_token
>       return self._load_azure_token(provider)   File "/Users//works/test-kube-api-python/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py",
>   line 233, in _load_azure_token
>       self._refresh_azure_token(provider['config'])   File "/Users//works/test-kube-api-python/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py",
>   line 253, in _refresh_azure_token
>       refresh_token, client_id, '00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000')   File
>   "/Users//works/test-kube-api-python/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/adal/authentication_context.py",
>   line 236, in acquire_token_with_refresh_token
>       return self._acquire_token(token_func)   File "/Users//works/test-kube-api-python/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/adal/authentication_context.py",
>   line 128, in _acquire_token
>       return token_func(self)   File "/Users//works/test-kube-api-python/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/adal/authentication_context.py",
>   line 234, in token_func
>       return token_request.get_token_with_refresh_token(refresh_token, client_secret)   File
>   "/Users//works/test-kube-api-python/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/adal/token_request.py",
>   line 343, in get_token_with_refresh_token
>       return self._get_token_with_refresh_token(refresh_token, None, client_secret)   File
>   "/Users//works/test-kube-api-python/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/adal/token_request.py",
>   line 340, in _get_token_with_refresh_token
>       return self._oauth_get_token(oauth_parameters)   File "/Users//works/test-kube-api-python/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/adal/token_request.py",
>   line 112, in _oauth_get_token
>       return client.get_token(oauth_parameters)   File "/Users//works/test-kube-api-python/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/adal/oauth2_client.py",
>   line 291, in get_token
>       raise AdalError(return_error_string, error_response) adal.adal_error.AdalError: Get Token request returned http error: 400
>   and server response:
>   {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS65001: The user or
>   administrator has not consented to use the application with ID
>   '' named 'Kubernetes AD Client
>   '. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and
>   resource.\r\nTrace ID:
>   \r\nCorrelation ID:
>   \r\nTimestamp: 2019-10-14
>   12:32:35Z","error_codes":[65001],"timestamp":"2019-10-14
>   12:32:35Z","trace_id":"","correlation_id":"","suberror":"consent_required"}

I really don't understand why it doesn't work.

When I use kubectl, all work fine.

I read some docs but I'm not sure to understand the adal error.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

- Login as a tenant admin to https://portal.azure.com
- Open the registration for your app in the
- Go to Settings then Required Permissions
- Press the Grant Permissions button

If you are not a tenant admin, you cannot give admin consent

From https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi/issues/19

Comment: No, Op is not using any app registration, Op is using Kubectl python client which loads the auth information from the local kube config file. I am also getting `ImportError: refresh token error, adal library not imported` error.

Answer (score 0):

This is [good post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69753834/1176573) where you can find snippet to authenticate to AKS:

```py
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.containerservice import ContainerServiceClient
from azure.mgmt.containerservice.models import (ManagedClusterAgentPoolProfile,
                                                ManagedCluster)

credential = AzureCliCredential()
subscription_id = "XXXXX"
resource_group= 'MY-RG'
resouce_client=ResourceManagementClient(credential,subscription_id)
container_client=ContainerServiceClient(credential,subscription_id)
resouce_list=resouce_client.resources.list_by_resource_group(resource_group)
```

Note: You need to install respective Az Python SKD libraries.