# Azure-sdk-for-python AKS- How to get available latest version for Kubernetes on AKS

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, azure-aks

I'm trying to get available versions of Kubernetes on AKS via python.sdk and upgrade the AKS with the latest version afterwards.

Here is what I've tried considering this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/managed-clusters/get-upgrade-profile

```
for resource in list(resource_list):
    if resource.type== "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters":
       print("ResourceName:", resource.name, "ResourceType:", resource.type)
       containerservice_client = ContainerServiceClient(credential, sub.subscription_id)
       get_aks = containerservice_client.managed_clusters.get(group.name, resource.name)
       aks_get_upgrade = containerservice_client.managed_clusters.get_upgrade_profile(group.name, resource.name)
       print("AKSGetUpdate", aks_get_upgrade)
```

However it doesn't return kubernetesVersion.

I would appreciate if someone can help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the below code , which I used to test in my environment:

```
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.containerservice import ContainerServiceClient
from azure.mgmt.containerservice.models import ManagedClusterPoolUpgradeProfileUpgradesItem

credential = AzureCliCredential()
subscription_id = "SUBID"
resource_group= 'RG'
resouce_client=ResourceManagementClient(credential,subscription_id)
container_client=ContainerServiceClient(credential,subscription_id)
resouce_list=resouce_client.resources.list_by_resource_group(resource_group)
for resource in list (resouce_list) :
    if resource.type == 'Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters':
       print("ResourceName:", resource.name, "ResourceType:", resource.type)
       get_aks = container_client.managed_clusters.get(resource_group, resource.name)
       aks_get_details = container_client.managed_clusters.get_upgrade_profile(resource_group, resource.name)
       aks_get_upgrade = aks_get_details.control_plane_profile
       upgrades = aks_get_upgrade.upgrades
       print("AKS_current_controlPlane", aks_get_upgrade.kubernetes_version)
       for i in upgrades:
           print("AKSGetUpdate_upgrade_controlPlane", i.kubernetes_version,i.is_preview)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I am wondering if get_upgrade_profile is like cli command: $ az aks get-upgrades? Because by printing out the one that you wrote, it gives me only one kubernetes version which seems it is the current version on AKS , not the list of available versions for upgrading?

Comment: under upgrades in the output of "controlPlaneProfile" I see only this:'upgrades': [<azure.mgmt.containerservice.v2021_09_01.models._models_py3.ManagedClusterPoolUpgradeProfileUpgradesItem object at 0x7ffb9d83d710>, <azure.mgmt.containerservice.v2021_09_01.models._models_py3.ManagedClusterPoolUpgradeProfileUpgradesItem object at 0x7ffb9d83db90>]}

Comment: yes , @Matrix, you are correct it gets the current Kubernetes_version and upgrades has the available versions. I just updated my query as per your requirement.

Comment: Very nice, thank you :)

Comment: @Matrix, Glad to be of help:)

Comment: Do you know which command can I use for upgrading to the new version using python sdk? Is it managed_clusters.upgradechannel?

Comment: Thanks for full snippet. Can you pl. edit my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58377154/1176573) as well I mean it pertains to [Python Kubectl Client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python)?