# Azure-sdk-for-python AKS- How to upgrade kubernetes on AKS

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, azure-aks

I've tried to find out which python sdk I can use for upgrading Kubernetes on AKS, in another word how to run this command via python sdk?

```
az aks upgrade --name mycluster --resource-group myrg --kubernetes-version newversion
```

however my search wasn't successful.

Here is a part of my function: init.py

```
import logging
from azure.mgmt.containerservice import ContainerServiceClient
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.mgmt.subscription import SubscriptionClient
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
....
for group in list(group_list):
              #print("ResourceGroupName:", group.name)
              resource_list = resource_client.resources.list_by_resource_group(group.name)
              print("Fetching AKS resource\n")
              
              for resource in list(resource_list):
                if resource.type== "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters":
                  print("ResourceName:", resource.name, "ResourceType:", resource.type)
                  containerservice_client = ContainerServiceClient(credential, sub.subscription_id)
                  
                  print("Getting availabele versions...\n")
                  aks_get_version = containerservice_client.managed_clusters.get_upgrade_profile(group.name, resource.name)
                  
                  
                  aks_get_upgrade = aks_get_version.control_plane_profile
                  upgrades = aks_get_upgrade.upgrades
                  print("AKS_current_controlPlane", aks_get_upgrade.kubernetes_version)
                  for i in upgrades:
                    print("AKSGetUpdate_upgrade_controlPlane", i.kubernetes_version,i.is_preview)
```

It seems

```
managed_clusters.update
```

can be a solution but then the question is how to pass properties.kubernetesVersion and properties.agentPoolProfiles[0].orchestratorVersion values in it?

```
parameters = {"properties.kubernetesVersion": i.kubernetes_version, "properties.agentPoolProfiles[0].orchestratorVersion": i.kubernetes_version}
containerservice_client.managed_clusters.create_or_update(group.name, resource.name, parameters)
```

However I get this error:

```
Exception: AttributeError: 'ManagedClustersOperations' object has no attribute 'create_or_update'
```

I would appreciate if someone can help with this.

**Updated**

Modified the code based on the given answer however it doesn't update my cluster and doesn't give me any error either, I don't know what I'm missing and how to do troubleshooting in this stage:

```
print("Getting availabele versions on AKS:", resource.name)
aks_get_version = containerservice_client.managed_clusters.get_upgrade_profile(group.name, resource.name)
            
aks_get_upgrade = aks_get_version.control_plane_profile
upgrades = aks_get_upgrade.upgrades
print("AKS_current_controlPlane", aks_get_upgrade.kubernetes_version)
                  
agent_pool=containerservice_client.agent_pools.list(group.name, resource.name)
 for i in upgrades:
      print("AKSAvailable_Versions_List:", i.kubernetes_version,i.is_preview)
      latest_version = i.kubernetes_version
 print("LatestVersion:", latest_version)  
                    
 for x in agent_pool:
     agent_pool_name=x.name
     print("Agent_Pool_Name:",x.name)
 ManagedClusterAgentPoolProfile(orchestrator_version=latest_version,name=agent_pool_name)

param=ManagedCluster(location=location, 
kubernetes_version=latest_version,agent_pool_profiles=[ManagedClusterAgentPoolProfile(orchestrator_version=latest_version,name=agent_pool_name,mode=x.mode,type=x.type_properties_type)])
              
update_aks=containerservice_client.managed_clusters.begin_create_or_update(resource_group_name=group.name ,resource_name=resource.name ,parameters=param)
```

OutPut:
AKS_current_controlPlane 1.19.11
LatestVersion: 1.20.9
Agent_Pool_Name: default

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT thanks for the comment. you mean I can't  pass it through parameters?

Comment: yes , you will be passing them in parameters but you have to select the kubernetes version you have to upgrade right from the list of options, so , i guess you will need to provide that in a input and store in a variable then pass it in parameters.. and if it it is a single output in the available upgrade then you can directly pass .. let me test it out and will get back here

Comment: nice, thank you then I'll hear from you :)

Comment: sure, I'll set it as accepted answer as soon as I finish with testing it.

Comment: updated the answer.. after testing as per the requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code which I have tested in my environment:

```
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.containerservice import ContainerServiceClient
from azure.mgmt.containerservice.models import (ManagedClusterAgentPoolProfile,
                                                ManagedCluster)

credential = AzureCliCredential()
subscription_id = "my sub"
resource_group= 'rg name'
resouce_client=ResourceManagementClient(credential,subscription_id)
container_client=ContainerServiceClient(credential,subscription_id)
resouce_list=resouce_client.resources.list_by_resource_group(resource_group)
for resource in list (resouce_list) :
    if resource.type == 'Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters':
       kub_name=resource.name
       location=resource.location
       print("ResourceName:", kub_name, "ResourceLocation:",location )
       get_aks = container_client.managed_clusters.get(resource_group, resource.name)
       aks_get_details = container_client.managed_clusters.get_upgrade_profile(resource_group, resource.name)
       aks_control_plane_upgrade = aks_get_details.control_plane_profile
       upgrades = aks_control_plane_upgrade.upgrades
       print("AKS_current_controlPlane_version:", aks_control_plane_upgrade.kubernetes_version)
       agent_pool=container_client.agent_pools.list(resource_group_name=resource_group, resource_name=kub_name)
       for i in upgrades:
           available_version=i.kubernetes_version
       print("Available_Versions_List:",available_version)
       #version_to_upgrade=input("PLease enter the version you want to upgrade to from the above list:")
       for x in agent_pool:
           agent_pool_name=x.name
           print("Agent_Pool_Name:",x.name)
       param=ManagedCluster(location=location, kubernetes_version=available_version,agent_pool_profiles=[ManagedClusterAgentPoolProfile(orchestrator_version=available_version,name=agent_pool_name,mode=x.mode,type=x.type_properties_type)])
       update_aks=container_client.managed_clusters.begin_create_or_update(resource_group_name=resource_group ,resource_name=kub_name ,parameters=param)
```

**Outputs:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you :) I'm testing it but it wasn't successful for me. can you please check the updated part of my question and let me know what I'm missing there?

Comment: Thanks for reply. the way that I print the latest_version is the last version that prints out. so the output is only one version: LatestVersion: 1.20.9. I didn't use input because I want to run this script automatic every week without I give it any input everytime. Do you think the problem is still coming from the version variable?

Comment: @Matrix, then i guess it shouldn't be a problem let me run from my side and see it that applies or not

Comment: @Matrix, i updated the code as per the requirement and it ran successfully , i have updated the answer as well

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's just started working fine :) At the end I was missing the role "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/agentpools/write" in azure function once I added it, it started upgrading.

Comment: np !! Glad to be of help!!

Comment: which version modules has been used? I'm getting hit by `AttributeError: 'AzureCliCredential' object has no attribute 'signed_session'`